# VS Code syntax highlighting for SQL commands in Python

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext3

[image]

The first syntax highlighting is of VS Code and the second one is of Sublime Text. I searched for extensions but I couldn't find anything which could detect SQL commands like `CREATE TABLE` and highlight them or suggest them as I start typing.

Sublime Text and Atom have this feature by default, but I can't get it to work in VS Code.

I am working with `.py` files so the syntax highlighting works only for Python commands and the whole text (inside quotes) is treated as string in VS Code.

Is there any fix to get syntax highlighting like Sublime Text / Atom in VS Code when working with SQL syntax in `.py` files or highlighting commands even if it's inside quotes ("")?

Answer (score 6):

It seems the VS Code doesn't support this feature officially.
Hence, I make an extension called [Highlight String Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iuyoy.highlight-string-code) which can highlight SQL expressions in Python or any other language.

You can easily use it by **uppercasing** the first *keyword* of the SQL command and adding a semicolon at the end:

[image]

I hope the extension can be helpful.

Comment: brilliant extension! Works right away, thanks a lot!