# MySQL syntax highlighting overwritten in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: What it's supposed to be]

This is what it's "Supposed to" look like

But it gets overwritten no matter what theme I use, (even the default theme).

[image: What it shows]

I already have an extension for "String Code", but it gets overwritten by the theme.

eg : When loading, the first pic shows first but then gets overwritten (see second pic).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code syntax highlighting for sql commands in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559884/vs-code-syntax-highlighting-for-sql-commands-in-python)

Comment: @SurajRao it still gets overwritten by the theme, unfortunately.

Comment: which theme are you using? any theme extension? You could add this info in the question

Comment: Currently using [Github Dark Default] theme. But no matter what theme I use, even the Default ones, it gets overwritten either way.

Comment: Did you try having `--sql`? https://github.com/iuyoy/highlight-string-code#usages

Comment: It works but gets overwritten by the theme.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.